# MySQL: LIKE Wildcard inside WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database, select, inner-join, wildcard

I SELECT data from a MySQL database and I'm trying to replace `WHERE column_name = 'name'` with a wildcard like `WHERE column_name LIKE '%name%'`.
Sounds too easy, right?

The original code (which works perfectly) looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.title_id, a.artist_id, fe_title.title, fe_artist.artist
FROM fe_title_artist AS a 
INNER JOIN fe_title ON a.title_id = fe_title.id
INNER JOIN fe_artist ON a.artist_id = fe_artist.id
INNER JOIN fe_title_artist AS b 
WHERE a.title_id=b.title_id 
and b.artist_id=(SELECT id FROM fe_artist WHERE artist = 'Patrick Duffy')
```

What I tried and failed with looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.title_id, a.artist_id, fe_title.title, fe_artist.artist
FROM fe_title_artist AS a 
INNER JOIN fe_title ON a.title_id = fe_title.id
INNER JOIN fe_artist ON a.artist_id = fe_artist.id
INNER JOIN fe_title_artist AS b 
WHERE a.title_id=b.title_id 
and b.artist_id=(SELECT id FROM fe_artist WHERE artist LIKE '%Patrick%')
```

No results on this one.

Is a wildcard within a where clause just too much? Is the self join causing the problem? Is there a way to code this differently? Am I just stupid?

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: mmm that should work the same. Did you try just `SELECT id FROM fe_artist WHERE artist LIKE '%Patrick%'` ??

Comment: The part ```artist_id=``` might be the problem. It will expect a single result from the sub-select. Try ```artist_id in (SELECT```.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I was thinking the same. But OP said didnt get any result. But yes if you expect multiple result you should change to `artist_id IN (...)`

Comment: Take a look, Google mysql select where in subquery

Comment: Thank you Sloan, thank you @Juan, this was the case and it works now! And note to myself: I need to do more basic tutorials on mysql.

Comment: So why you didnt got any error? Are you using PHP without error handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to Subquery returns more than 1 rows. Please use below Query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.title_id, a.artist_id, fe_title.title, fe_artist.artist
FROM fe_title_artist AS a 
INNER JOIN fe_title ON a.title_id = fe_title.id
INNER JOIN fe_artist ON a.artist_id = fe_artist.id
INNER JOIN fe_title_artist AS b 
WHERE a.title_id=b.title_id 
and b.artist_id IN (SELECT id FROM fe_artist WHERE artist LIKE '%Patrick%')
```